# Set value of Reactstrap's Input to empty string

Tags: reactjs, reactstrap

How do I set the value of a Reactstrap Input to be empty? I am using code like this.

```
handleChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({message: event.target.value});
};
```

< Input onChange = {this.handleChange}/>

Also, what is the best practice for getting the value of an input: refs or onChange?

Answer (score 1):

You gotta set a value property for your input which holds the value of your input, so your input looks like this:

```
<Input value={this.state.message} onChange={this.handleChange} />
```

and then when you want to clear its value, you just do this:

```
this.setState({message: ''})
```

and for your other question, the answer is that the Refs provide a way to access DOM nodes or React elements created in the render method, according to React documentation You can use Refs when:

- Managing focus, text selection, or media playback.
- Triggering imperative animations.
- Integrating with third-party DOM libraries.

and you have to AVOID using refs for anything that can be done **declaratively**.
Then, here we just use onChange because we don't simply need Refs!

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign state value to your input field.

```
public class myApp() extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            message: ''
        };
    }

    handleChange = (event) => {
        this.setState({message: event.target.value});
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <Input value={this.state.message} onChange={this.handleChange} />
        );
    }
}
```